# Google maps - draw multiple separate polylines

Tags: google-maps, google-polyline

So I am trying to draw multiple separated polylines on google map.
So far I don't have so much:

```
<script>
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.97559, 4.12565);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: center,
   zoom: 12,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map
});  

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// start coordinates
var start = ['51.97559, 4.12565', 
             '55.46242, 8.43872', 
             '49.49259, 0.1065',
             '50.36862, -4.13412']

// end coordinates
var end = ['51.94784, 1.2539', 
           '51.74784, 1.2539', 
           '50.79726, -1.11048',
           '43.45846, -3.80685']

function initialize() {
    for (var i=0; i < end.length; i++){
      calcRoute(start[i], end [i]);
    }
}

function calcRoute(source,destination){
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
     path: [],
     strokeColor: 'red',
     strokeWeight: 2,
     strokeOpacity: 1
  });

  polyline.setMap(map);          
}
</script>
```

I found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b7FHV/) an interesting example, but it has DirectionsTravelMode, and I want only a straight line between two points.
So in my example I would like to have 4 not connected straight lines drawn on the map.

Comment: you didn't fill the path of the polyline(s)

Comment: I don't know with what should I fill it :/

Comment: e.g. with `source` and `destination`  (It's not clear what the expected result should be) `path: [source,destination]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. a google.maps.LatLng object is two numbers; or a google.maps.LatLngLiteral is a javascript object with a lat and a lng property, neither is a string.

```
for (var i=0; i < end.length; i++){
  var startCoords = start[i].split(",");
  var startPt = new google.maps.LatLng(startCoords[0],startCoords[1]);
  var endCoords = end[i].split(",");
  var endPt = new google.maps.LatLng(endCoords[0],endCoords[1]);
  calcRoute(startPt, endPt);
  bounds.extend(startPt);
  bounds.extend(endPt);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

2. you need to add those to the polyline's path:

```
function calcRoute(source,destination){
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
     path: [source, destination],
     strokeColor: 'red',
     strokeWeight: 2,
     strokeOpacity: 1
  });

  polyline.setMap(map);          
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jjw8vj7a/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.97559, 4.12565);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // start coordinates
  var start = ['51.97559, 4.12565',
    '55.46242, 8.43872',
    '49.49259, 0.1065',
    '50.36862, -4.13412'
  ]

  // end coordinates
  var end = ['51.94784, 1.2539',
    '51.74784, 1.2539',
    '50.79726, -1.11048',
    '43.45846, -3.80685'
  ]

  for (var i = 0; i < end.length; i++) {
    var startCoords = start[i].split(",");
    var startPt = new google.maps.LatLng(startCoords[0], startCoords[1]);
    var endCoords = end[i].split(",");
    var endPt = new google.maps.LatLng(endCoords[0], endCoords[1]);
    calcRoute(startPt, endPt);
    bounds.extend(startPt);
    bounds.extend(endPt);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function calcRoute(source, destination) {
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [source, destination],
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 1
  });

  polyline.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice answer by [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) !

A small improvement, instead of adding many polyline elements to your map (which could later require you to keep track of them & iterate over all of them in order to remove or change them), you can put all paths in one Polygon object.

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syoels/hyh81jfz/1/
(i took geocodezip's fiddle and made small changes)

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {

  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.97559, 4.12565);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // start coordinates
  var start = ['51.97559, 4.12565',
    '55.46242, 8.43872',
    '49.49259, 0.1065',
    '50.36862, -4.13412'
  ];

  // end coordinates
  var end = ['51.94784, 1.2539',
    '51.74784, 1.2539',
    '50.79726, -1.11048',
    '43.45846, -3.80685'
  ];

  var paths = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < end.length; i++) {
    var startCoords = start[i].split(",");
    var startPt = new google.maps.LatLng(startCoords[0], startCoords[1]);
    var endCoords = end[i].split(",");
    var endPt = new google.maps.LatLng(endCoords[0], endCoords[1]);
    paths.push([startPt, endPt]);

    bounds.extend(startPt);
    bounds.extend(endPt);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var polyline = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: paths,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 1
  });

  polyline.setMap(map);

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```